# Sorting results using "ORDER BY CASE" not using primary index

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I'm trying to do a sorting using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM client 
ORDER BY 
CASE $desired_colum_to_order
   WHEN 'id' then `id`
   WHEN 'name' then `name`
   ELSE `id`
END
ASC
```

The problem is that this query is ordering ID as a string column, but it is a **Integer Primary Key**.

The results become in this order:
*10, 11, 12, 13, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9*

If I do the following query, MySQL orders correctly:

```
SELECT * FROM client 
ORDER BY 
id
ASC
```

Now the results become in correct order:
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13

Could someone explain me why is MySQL ordering like this, if is the same column in both queries?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q: Could someone explain me why is MySQL ordering like this?**

MySQL is "ordering" the rows based on the *result* of the *expression* in the ORDER BY clause.

You've supplied a `CASE` expression in the ORDER BY clause. And that expression returns a single datatype. In this case, it appears that the expression is returning a **`VARCHAR`**, likely based on the datatype of the `name` column.

The optimizer isn't "smart enough" to figure out that the string literal `'id'` following the `CASE` keyword will *always* match the string literal `'id'` following the first `WHEN`. You see that, but the optimizer doesn't.

You read that expression, and you see that the first `WHEN` will be matched for every row, and that the expression always return `id`, and that the expression will never return `name`.

You see that as equivalent to specifying `ORDER BY id`.

But the optimizer doesn't it look at it that way. It sees `name` as a possible return value, and it settles on a datatype that "works" for all of the possible return values. In this case, it looks like it's determining that `VARCHAR` is the appropriate datatype to return.

If the return datatype from the CASE expression was integer, then rows would be sorted in ascending numeric value.

But MySQL still wouldn't be able to use an index to return the rows in order, it's still going to perform a "Using filesort" operation, because the rows are still being ordered by the result of an expression, rather than a column.

Comment: Thanks for explaination, it makes sense to me now! Marked as Right answer!

Comment: It's important to note that this "expected behaviour" was not a thing until Mysql 5.7.12, and presumably stopped being a thing in 5.7.14.

This of course does nothing for those of us using AWS Aurora which was irresponsibly frozen on 5.7.12, but that's another conversation.

Comment: @kamii: I'm pretty sure your comment isn't relevant. I'm pretty sure this behavior can be observed in MySQL 5.6 and the latest versions of 5.7.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the `order by` into different conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM client 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN $desired_colum_to_order = 'id' then id END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN $desired_colum_to_order = 'name' then name END) ASC,
         id ASC
```

This works because the `case` statements that do not match all return `NULL`, which has no order.  If none match, then the final `id` will be the one used.  The advantage of different `case` statements is that each column is "type" safe.  Also, you can fiddle with the logic to make some `DESC` instead of `ASC`.

Comment: Yes, the first id is actually $desired_column_to_order. And the example is shortened, the real query have like 10 'WHEN' clauses

Comment: Your solution for my problem is working, nice answer, it works as I want to!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `CASE` expression evaulates to string because that data type is the best common one what MySQL found.

An option is to split your case statement to all available columns like this:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE $orderColumn = 'id' THEN id ELSE 0 END
  , CASE $orderColumn = 'name' THEN name ELSE '' END
```

Another option is to zerofill the numeric fields like this:

```
ORDER BY
CASE $desired_colum_to_order
   WHEN 'id' then LPAD(CONVERT(`id`,VARCHAR(20)),20,'0')
   WHEN 'name' then `name`
   ELSE `id`
END
```

Or (and I think this is the best option if available): Build your query in your application to dynamically add the required `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: Your 3rd solution is the simpliest, but nice for me, because the query is small and fast. Other two solutions does not apply. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your case statement:

```
CASE $desired_colum_to_order
    WHEN 'id' then `id`
    WHEN 'name' then `name`
    ELSE `id`
END
```

is an expression of type string -> string. The only alternative would have been string -> int, but how should name be interpreted as an int? What you can do is to split your comparision in two:

```
ORDER BY CASE $desired_colum_to_order WHEN 'name' then `name` else '' end
       , CASE $desired_colum_to_order WHEN 'id' then `id` else 0 end
```

The first CASE is an expression string -> string, the second one an expression string -> int. The CASE that is not relevant will map all values to the identity element for that type, hence does not affect the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` evaluates the result as a string. To get your desired result you could try :

```
SELECT * 
FROM client 
ORDER BY 
  CASE $desire_column_to_order
    WHEN 'name' THEN `name`
    ELSE 0
  END ASC, 
  `id` ASC
```

Comment: This works in my reduced example, but in the real example, I have more then one INTEGER column that user may select. In this case, the solution is not valid, but your solution is fine for some cases.

Comment: @EliasSoares, OK.. then I suggest you use the answer provided by Gordon.. You can also group the integer columns into one `CASE` and the string columns into another.. so you only need two cases.

Comment: Nice, I will use Gordon solution, and your suggestion to group same datatypes in case groups.